# System.FormatException on Int32 from string

Tags: c#, exception

I am getting System.FormatException when i get input of region. tell me the solution as soon as possible.

```
        double price;
        int region;
        string p;
        Console.Write("Enter the total price of items : ");
        price= Console.Read();
        Console.WriteLine("Select the your region.");
        Console.WriteLine("1 : Pakistan");
        Console.WriteLine("2 : UK");
        Console.WriteLine("3 : Cortia");
        p= Console.ReadLine();
        region = Convert.ToInt32(p);
```

Comment: you have entered badly formatted text - inspect p in the debugger

Comment: you are not typing a number value, that's the reason of the exception

Comment: if he types 1.50 in the price the read() will only take 1 and assign .50 to p and the decimal point will cause this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your price is double type but you have tried to assign value from console input as string, convert it to double will solve the problem, also use TryParse for conversion, that will catch all exception during conversion.

```
double price;
int region;
Console.Write("Enter the total price of items : ");
double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out price);
Console.WriteLine("Select the your region.");
Console.WriteLine("1 : Pakistan");
Console.WriteLine("2 : UK");
Console.WriteLine("3 : Cortia");
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out region);
```

Comment: why would that fix a format exception? Console.Read returns an Int that is implicitly converted to double

Comment: it is the convert.int32 that will fail with formatexcpetion

Comment: this line `price= Console.Read();` should be `price= Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: solution work. but sir at that time i am getting error on last line. and the problem is in " price= Console.Read(); " why this is happening.

Comment: hard to know, in my pc it find the exception in the line of `price`

Comment: @HacanChamp see my latest update this will prevent input exception for both `price` and `region`

Answer (score 2):

You could use the TryParse, you check if you can transform the input to the int value before you do so.

Your could use the TryParse in the price also.

```
        double price;
        int region;
        string p;
        Console.Write("Enter the total price of items : ");
        price = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Select the your region.");
        Console.WriteLine("1 : Pakistan");
        Console.WriteLine("2 : UK");
        Console.WriteLine("3 : Cortia");
        p = Console.ReadLine();

        if (!int.TryParse(p, out region))
        {
            //error handle.
        }
        else
        {
                //at this point, the region value already has the value of p;
        }
```